# IOS Release and assignment messages differences for nsstring

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, nsstring, manual-retain-release

I was going through the memory management concepts. I created one `string1` and assign that `string1` into another `string2`, now I release this `string1`.
Here `string2` retain count is 1 but on `NSLog` statement it gives EXC Bad access.

When I am assigning the string

```
NSString * string1 = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"hello"];
string2 = string1;

NSLog(@"string1 memory address = %p, string2 memory address = %p", &string1, &string2);

[string1 release];

NSLog(@"[string2 retainCount] = %lu", (unsigned long)[string2 retainCount]);
NSLog(@"string2 = %@", string2); // here app is crashing
```

Does it means that string2 has an autorelease message also with it because if I do `string2 = [string1 copy];` instead of `string2 = string1;` it doesn't crash.
So I wanted to ask whether the crash is because it has autorelease message of `string2` and how it is relating with `string2` release command.
Please advice!

Comment: I think this link can help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702540/nsstring-release

Comment: 1. Retain count is meaningless. 2.Use ARC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assignment doesn't change object's retain count if you use manual memory management in Objective-C. And you for sure use it, otherwise, you can't invoke `release` method in your code.

So, your code does the following. It creates `NSString` object with retain count = 1, and assigns it to `string1` pointer. After that, you assigns `string1` to `string2`. Now you have 2 pointers to the same object, and retain count of this object is still 1. Then you release object, it deallocated immediately. And after that you experiencing crash:

```
NSString * string1 = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"hello"]; // string retain count is 1 
string2 = string1; // 2 pointers to same string, retain count is still 1
[string1 release]; // string is deallocated when retain count drops to 0
NSLog(@"string2 = %@", string2); // here app is crashing
```

To fix that, you can use `retain` when you do an assignment.

```
NSString * string1 = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"hello"]; // string retain count is 1
string2 = [string1 retain]; // 2 pointers to same string, retain count is 2
[string1 release]; // string retain count back to 1
NSLog(@"string2 = %@", string2); // no crash
```

Also, you can use `copy`. Note that for `NSString` copy doesn't actually copies an object, it simply invokes `retain`. There is no need to perform actual copying, because `NSString` is immutable and can't be changed. If we will use `NSMutableString`, things will change:

```
NSMutableString * string1 = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithFormat:@"hello"]; // string retain count is 1
NSMutableString * string2 = [string1 copy]; // 2 separate strings, both have retain count 1
[string1 release]; // string1 is deallocated
NSLog(@"string2 = %@", string2); // no crash, string2 retain count is 1
```

Alternatively, you can use ARC. It will insert corresponding retain/release calls at compile time. Code then will look like:

```
NSString * string1 = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"hello"];
string2 = string1;
string1 = nil;
NSLog(@"string2 = %@", string2); // no crash
```

I suggest to understand manual memory management first, and after that migrate to ARC.

Comment: Thanks for the detail explanation, just one doubt, string2 = string1; // 2 pointers to same string, retain count is still 1 does it means that the memory address of string 1 and string 2 will be same, because when I am printing the memory address they are different. so 2 pointers to same string, pls explain in terms of memory locations and address. Pls.

Comment: `string1` and `string2` are already C pointers, you don't need to take their addresses in `NSLog`. Use the following code instead `NSLog(@"string1 memory address = %p, string2 memory address = %p", string1, string2);`, and you'll see that they are pointing to the same address.

Comment: Thanks Boris for clarity. It helps a lot.